# Return value for a hooked function

Tags: c++, hook, detours

I've been hooking some functions in order to make a protection for my app, I'm using Detours (CDetour), I'm hooking [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), my hook function must be exact as the original one.

```
HANDLE WINAPI CreateThreadHook( LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, SIZE_T dwStackSize, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress, LPVOID
            lpParameter, DWORD dwCreationFlags, LPDWORD lpThreadId )
{
    //do hooking stuff here
}
```

The hook works fine, the problem is that according to msdn `If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the new thread.` But since the function is hooked, the return value will be whatever I return, changing the hooked function to void or another type will only make the call have no return value, mostly leading to a crash. How can I return the value that should be returned by the original function?

Comment: What on earth are you actually trying to achieve? If you hook a function that creates a thread, then you must, of course, create a thread within the hook, right? So, what do you think that `CreateThread` call will return? Whether you then do something else with the arguments to the thread, store some useful data after the CreateThread returns, etc, is up to you. But it's unlikely that the code calling CreateThread will function correctly, if you don't actually create a thread.

Comment: .Cheersandhth.-Alf, after searching a lot, there is no documentation about it, only had to read the source, thanks to @MatsPetersson for setting me to the right direction. My guess was that the hooked function was an exit method from the original, which in actually it took place, virtualizing it was enough!